# With Esper how to start a window for X minutes from first event timestamp?

Tags: time, esper

I am trying to start a window and to make it lives for X minutes.

```
Select a,b
from Event.win:time(120) -> this gives me a sliding window
match_recognize(
partition by sensor
...
)
```

I tried also

```
Select a,b
from Event.win:ext_timed(time.time, 120) -> this gives me a sliding window as well
match_recognize(
partition by sensor
...
)
```

Is there a way to start a window for 120sec from the first coming event and to end it even new events are coming?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a start processing events when a certain event/time occurred and stop processing after X minutes then that is done with contexts.

```
create context FromNowForXSeconds start @now end after X seconds;
context FromNowForXSeconds select ... from ....;
```

Answer (score 0):

With `match recognize` you can set up partitioned windows with `interval`.

With the optional `interval` keyword and time period you can control how long the runtime should wait for further events to arrive that may be part of a matching event sequence, before indicating a match.

For example, from EPL reference chapter 8.8 ... the interval timer below starts at the arrival of the first event matching a sequence for a partition.

```
TemperatureSensorEvent
match_recognize (
partition by device
measures A.id as a_id, count(B.id) as count_b, first(B.id) as first_b, last(B.id)
 as last_b
pattern (A B*)
interval 5 seconds
define 
 A as A.temp > 100,
 B as B.temp > 100)
```